# Blocking operation in coroutines

Tags: spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, project-reactor

I am working on webflux application using coroutines. It's main purpose is "backend for frontend" for mobile app. Most of request is handled by fetching data and merging data from microservices. I am currently working on adding database to this service. I thought i understood this concept in coroutines. I tried adding this to code

```
    suspend fun fetchData(): String {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Thread.sleep(10000) // fetch data from database
            ""
        }
    }
```

I was surprised that this code used on one of endpoints slowed down every endpoint response time. Endpoints unrelated to this part of code where affected. My guess is I am using wrong pool thread for this operation. I also tried Reactor approach but got the same result:

```
    suspend fun fetchData(): String {
        return Mono.fromCallable {
            Thread.sleep(10000) // fetch data from database
            ""
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).awaitSingle()
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why main thread seems to get blocked?

Comment: Both Kotlin and Reactor uses a bounded thread pool for IO which means given a high number of concurrent requests they will need to spend time waiting in a queue. Your best bet would be to use an async (preferably also non-blocking) database client. If that's not possible you can either customize the thread pool size for these pools via system properties, or use your own dedicated thread pool.